# Error 500 when deployig my first Servlet in NetBeans using Tomcat server

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

Greeting to you all,
I am trying to build my first web app in NetBeans base on a simple tutorial I found online.
This is a screenshot of my files
[File organisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSOgj.png)
This is the content of my servlet

```
package hello;
 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
 
   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws IOException, ServletException {
      // Set the response message's MIME type (in Content-Type response header)
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      // Get an output Writer to write the response message over the network
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      // Write the response message (in an HTML page) to display "Hello, world!"
      try {
         out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head><title>Hello Servlet</title></head>");
         out.println("<body><h1>Hello, World (from Java Servlet)!</h1></body>");
         out.println("</html>");
      } finally {
         out.close();  // Always close the output writer
      }
   }
}
```

This the content of my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServletExample</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>hello.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServletExample</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sayhello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

But I am getting this error page in my browser
[tomcat error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwNMt.png)

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a note, I strongly recommend against learning to hand-write servlets as an introduction to Web applications; it's not the way things have been done for at least 15 years. Instead, learn a framework like Spring MVC with Spring Boot (here's [an actual runnable Web application](https://twitter.com/rob_winch/status/364871658483351552)) or Micronaut, which will handle all of the messy details like format conversion and closing the writer and will let you instead spend your effort on your application's logic.

Comment: Thank you for your advice . I would however be happy to  figure out what is the issue here this project.

Comment: @SidoineSamoDjossi - Your servlet code and configurations in `web.xml` is absolutely correct. The problem may be because of configurations in NetBeans. I personally like Eclipse or STS and with the same servlet code and configurations in `web.xml, you can run this servlet with Eclipse/STS successfully in a couple of clicks.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thanks a lot Sir. I think the problem is really with NetBeans.